# Como mudar a cor de uma div antes de carregar a página através de um script?

Tags: javascript, html

Eu estou a tentar escolher a cor de fundo de uma `div` através de um script.
Ou seja, o meu objectivo é que mal a página apareça já tenha corrido o script e tenha aparecido a cor que o script seleccionou.

A minha questão por agora é:

```
<body onload="funcaoquemudaacor()">
```

Pelo visto, o parâmetro **onload** não me parece o mais correcto, e não está a resultar.

É esse o meu erro? Soluções?

Comment: Por que não usar CSS? Realmente `onload` só vai carregar a função JavaScript após carregar o `body`. Uma alternativa é deixar o conteúdo da página invisível e após carregar torná-la visível com a cor desejada.

Comment: Porque o script é que vai escolher o css que vai usar, para poder alterar a cor de fundo da div conforme o caso... vou experimentar, obrigada.

Comment: São necessários mais detalhes para te dar uma resposta coerente com o que você deseja fazer. O HTML será produzido dinamicamente pelo seu JavaScript, ou a página é entregue já contendo o HTML e o JavaScript deve alterar a cor assim que possível?

Comment: Se não há como adicionar a cor na geração do HTML pelo servidor, uma alternativa é ocultar o elemento por padrão, então quando a página carregar, mude a cor e mostre o elemento.

Comment: **Vote hoje! Vote amanhã! Vote sempre! vote consciente!** O seu voto é muito importante para nossa comunidade, contribua conosco e ajude a tornar a Stack Overflow em Português(SOpt) cada vez maior. Você pode saber mais em: [**Vote cedo, vote frequentemente**](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/159/vote-cedo-vote-frequentemente)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o objetivo é mudar a cor de uma determinada div, o primeiro momento em que isso pode ser feito é assim que a div passar a existir na página. Por exemplo:

```
<!-- esta é a sua div: -->
<div id="minhadiv">...</div>
<script>
funcaoquemudaacor();
</script>
```

Naturalmente, a `funcaoquemudaacor` também já precisa existir nesse momento, então deve ser declarada no mesmo bloco `<script>` que a chamada, ou incluída antes desse bloco se for um arquivo js externo.

O `onload` que você usou espera a página toda carregar, incluindo todas as imagens e demais arquivos externos.

Comment: Na verdade, voce pode declarar tanto antes quanto depois de invocar uma função, muito desenvolvedor web tem a prática de escrever alguns códigos JS no final do html para ter um carregar mais rápido dos componentes de tela, já que o js só executa após toda tela carregada mesmo.

Comment: @MichelSimões Editei para ficar mais claro o que eu quis dizer. Não é verdade que o js só executa após toda a tela ter carregado, cada bloco/tag script é executado imediatamente após ser encontrado e parseado no código-fonte do HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Experimente utilizar o atributo style:

```
<div style="background-color: #000000">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

a forma de declarar no onload está correta.... posta pra gente a funcao por favor...
vc pode testar q provavelmente funcionará

```
 <script>
       function funcaoQueMudaDeCor(){
         document.getElemmentById('idDaDiv').style.backgroundColor= "#000"; 
      }
 </script>
```

Lembrando que pra essa funcao funcionar o que vem depois do style. deve ser a mesma propriedade atribuida no css da div. Se voce tentar com uma div declarada no css com o atributo "background: " provavelmente ela nao seja sobreposta pelo código js "backgroundColor".
 QQer coisa posta todo o js e css q ajuda.

Answer (score -2):

Usa o .ready do jquery. Creio que funciona. Acho q vai ter q colocar o script na `<head>`

Comment: O `ready` não executa antes de carregar a página, não importa onde ele esteja.